# FastApi value is not a valid dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, rest, fastapi

Я описал метод api, что бы туда передавать огромный json из набора ключ - значение. Я не хочу описывать каждое поле модели в BaseModel, так как их там около 100, я уже описал их в классе Plan. Я хочу просто при вызове метода создавать объект своего кастомного класса Plan и передавать туда json.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Json
#from models import Plan
from typing import Dict

class Item(BaseModel):

    params: Json[Dict[str, float]]

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/setPlan")
async def setPlan(params : Item):
    #plan = Plan.Plan(params.__dict__)
    #return plan.__dict__
    return {"params": params}
```

Когда я пытаюсь послать запрос и передать json:

```
import requests
import json

params = {
    "params" : {
        'point_break_even': float(2550000),
        'days_in_mount': float(22),
        'total_proceeds': float(2550000),

        'proceed_input_percent': float(21.95),

        'hookah_average_check': float(333),
        'hookah_proceeds_percent': float(5.3),

        'bar_proceeds_percent': float(65.72),
        'bar_people_count': float(11339),
        'bar_average_check': float(500),

        'kitchen_proceeds_percent': float(7.03),
        'kitchen_average_check': float(329),

        'bar_foodcost': float(-51.5),
        'bar_products_write_off_percent': float(-0.04),
        'bar_surplus_percent': float(1.5),
        'bar_failure_percent': float(-0.5),

        'kitchen_foodcost_percent': float(-45),
        'kitchen_products_write_off_percent': float(-1.5),
        'kitchen_surplus_percent': float(1.0),
        'kitchen_failure_percent': float(-1.0),

        'fot_labor_zp_povar_percent': float(-25.0),
        'fot_labor_povar_compensation_rub': int(0),
        'fot_labor_povar_mat_help_rub': int(0),

        'fot_labor_admin_zp_rub': int(-40000),
        'fot_labor_admin_zp_bonus_rub': int(0),
        'fot_labor_admin_zp_compensation_rub': int(0),
        'fot_labor_admin_zp_mat_help_rub': int(0),

        'fot_zp_zvukar': int(0),
        'fot_zp_zavhoz': int(0),
        'fot_zp_officiants': int(0),
        'fot_zp_cashiers': int(0),
        'fot_zp_hostes': int(0),
        'fot_zp_barmans': int(0),
        'total_loosers_zp': int(-300000),

        'fot_zp_manager': int(-40000),
        'fot_zp_bu_calc_kadr': int(-103000),
        'fot_zp_admin_po_rejimy': int(-132000),

        'personal_apartments_rent_rub': int(0),
        'personal_food_cost_percent': float(-0.68),
        'personal_transport_cost_rub': int(0),
        'personal_medicaments_medosmotr_rub': int(0),
        'personal_registration_in_ufms_rub': int(0),

        'rental_of_premises_rub': int(-500000),
        'communal_rent': int(0),
        'wanish_cost_percent': float(-0.16),
        'parking_coupons_rub': int(0),
        'room_maintenance_rub': int(0),
        'dizenfection_rub': int(-3003),
        'kovri_ot_gryazi_rub': int(0),
        'to_kts_rub': int(-7000),
        'garbage_removal_rub': int(0),

        'premises_capital_remont_rub': int(0),
        'premises_cosmetical_remont_rub': int(-15000),
        'furniture_updating_rub': int(-10000),
        'equipment_updating_rub': int(0),
        'equipment_remont_service_rub': int(0),
        'air_conditioning_remont_service_rub': int(0),
        'ventilation_remont_service_rub': int(0),
        'lamp_remont_service_rub': int(0),
        'electric_remont_service_rub': int(0),
        'canalization_remont_service_rub': int(0),
        'posuda_inventar_updating_percent': float(-0.35),
        'kitchen_inventar_service_rub': int(-7000),

        'orgtechnic_and_cassovie': int(-2500),
        'packaging_rub': int(0),
        'hoztovars_percent': float(-0.4),
        'prochie_rashodniki_percent': float(-0.14),

        'stationery_rub': int(-2500),

        # Прочие расходные материалы (значки, браслеты, телефоны POS-материалы, наклейки, дым, номерки, пейджеры)
        'znachki_rub': int(0),
        'phone_rub': int(0),
        'nomerki_rub': int(0),
        'pos_packages_rub': int(0),
        'control_brasslets_rub': int(0),
        'eticet_pistol_rub': int(0),
        'button_call': int(0),
        'padger': int(0),
        'smoke': int(0),
        'stickers': int(0),

        # Расходы на связь
        'internet_connection_rub': int(-1500),
        'post_office_rub': int(0),
        'phone_connection_rub': int(-1000),

        'transport_rub': int(0),
        'it_and_po_rub': int(-10500),
        'kkm_rub': int(-1400),
        'sas_standart_lab_issled_rub': int(0),
        'musical_design_of_music_rub': int(-12560),
        'sbis_ofd_rub': int(-1620),
        'cctv_and_control_rub': int(0),

        # Финансовые расходы
        'expenses_acquiring_percent': float(-1.05),
        'expenses_banking_service_percent': float(-0.09),

        # налоги и отчисления
        'income_tax_usn_envd_rub': int(0),
        'soc_fonds_percent': float(-0.93),
        'taxes_fees_fines_rub': int(0),

        # Реклама и маркетинг
        'fot_adv_specialists_rub': int(-128000),
        'marketing_events_percent': float(-5.0),

        # P3
        'p3_accountant_rub': int(-30000),
        'p3_royalty_rub': int(0),
        'p3_xx_rub': int(0)
    }
}

r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/setPlan', json = json.dumps(params))
print(r.json())
```

То я получаю следующую ошибку: `{'detail': [{'loc': ['body'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid dict', 'type': 'type_error.dict'}]}`

[image: Дока по сгенерированному методу]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вместо

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/setPlan', json = json.dumps(params))
```

вот так:

```
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/setPlan', json = params)
```

Оно работало, просто дампов никаких выполнять не нужно, сразу dict проталкиваем туда. Метод работал, я не верно передавал данные.

Comment: Можно и с json.dumps, но передавать тогда нужно через параметр data. `data=json.dumps(params)` по сути аналогично `json=params`, при использовании параметра json requests сам внутри вызовет json.dumps. Если вы перед передачей в json еще добавляете json.dumps, получается что вы два раза в json конвертируете.